# Django.urls reversing urls through multiple url pattern lists within one app

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-urls

I have a url.py inside my project which includes the following urls.py (belongs to my app).

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path,include
from .views import Index, Foo

bar_urlpatterns = [
path('foo/', Foo.as_view(), name='foo'),
]
        
urlpatterns = [
path('', Index.as_view(), name='index'),       
path('bar/', include(bar_urlpatterns)),]
```

I'm trying to outsource the subpaths of a path. The docs says the function `include` can include
a `pattern_list` and when i call the url`"http://myurl/foo/bar"` directly, this seems to hold true. I can also load the view via ajax directly when i give it the string.

But when i try to use the reverse `{%url 'foo'}` url template tag this throws:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags(at ...)
```

Doing the same thing with non-outsourced url patterns works perfectly fine for me.

The **html elements** where i use the function:

```
<a onclick="load_tab_view({% url "foo" %})">Foo</a>

<div id="tab_view_replaceable"></div>
```

**js** (works fine with my other views)

```
function load_tab_view(url){
    replace_id = 'tab_view_replaceable';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                $('#'+replace_id).html(data);
            }
        });
    
}
```

**Is there a way in which im still able to outsource my subpaths and make use of the reverse url template tag?**

(I dont want to create a new app for `bar`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use it if you put it in a different kind of quotation marks. So alternate between the 3 types.

In your case it should work like:

```
<a onclick="load_tab_view(`{% url 'foo' %}`)">Foo</a>
<div id="tab_view_replaceable"></div>
```

That's because JS doesn't take it as string otherwise.